# I'm getting strange, repeated results using spaCy and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, spacy

I'm making a bot that solves the New York Times "Connections" game. I'm trying to make a matrix that has the cosine similarities of words so that I can check to see which ones are most likely synonyms, but the matrix has this weird phenomenon of repeating rows and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
def synonym_detector(words):
    #takes in a list of strings, calculates the cosine similarity between all words.

    word_matrix = pd.DataFrame(columns = words, index = words)
    vectors = [nlp(x) for x in words]
    
    for i in range(len(vectors)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(vectors)):
            similarity = vectors[i].similarity(vectors[j])
            word_matrix.loc[words[i],words[j]] = similarity
    
    return word_matrix   
synonym_detector(['DAISY', 'ROSE', 'TULIP', 'VIOLET', 'BARN', 'CHICKEN', 'FARMER', 'TRACTOR','ASTER', 'CARPENTER', 'CRAVEN', 'WAN','DUST', 'LIFE', 'SPORTS', 'YELLOW'])
```

[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfhZI.png)

The output strangely has repeated rows and I cannot figure out why.
Additionally, .similary tests are giving me some weird answers. For example,

```
dust = nlp('dust')
yellow = nlp('yellow')
dust.similarity(yellow)
```

and I get 1.0.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: I don't see any repeated rows in that image.

Comment: `dust.similarity(yellow)` returns 0.326034887199003 for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `md` models with default vectors (not floret vectors) use the same vector for multiple words to save space. If you want a unique vector for each word in the vector table, use the `lg` model instead.

`md` vectors are created using the the `prune` option: https://spacy.io/api/cli#init-vectors